# Symfony - Showing Git Pushes/Commits info in html (plugin/bundle)

Tags: git, symfony, push, commit

I was wondering if anybody knows the right plugin/bundle for Symfony to show your Git Pushes/Commits?
I have tried a few myself before asking but didn't really found what I was looking for, just a simple plugin/bundle to show your Git info.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [GitElephantBundle](https://github.com/matteosister/GitElephantBundle) and [GitElephant library](https://github.com/matteosister/GitElephant).

Example usage:

```
// Log contains a collection of commit objects
// syntax: getLog(<tree-ish>, path = null, limit = 15, offset = null)
$log = $repo->getLog();
$log = $repo->getLog('master', null, 5);
$log = $repo->getLog('v0.1', null, 5, 10);
// or directly create a log object
$log = new Log($repo);
$log = new Log($repo, 'v0.1', null, 5, 10);
```